# палёнка = pálenka?

Tags: этимология

Недавно я наткнулся в чешском языке на слово "pálenka" - это такое фруктовое бренди. Первая ассоциация, пришедшая на ум - слово "палёнка" (алкоголь низкого качества).

Это может быть и полное заимствование, и просто ложный друг переводчика.

Если здесь есть специалисты, занимающиеся этимологией, подскажите пожалуйста - родственники эти слова, или нет.

Answer (score 4):

Both words derive from common Slavic root **pali-* ("to burn"), but in very different ways.

The Czech word refers to the technology of making the beverage, and has the same etymology as English "brandy" (which ultimately comes from a Germanic root meaning "to burn").

The Russian word comes from the slang word *палёный* "knockoff, counterfeit" which, as most Russian slang words, has an obscure etymology. In its direct sense, it means "burnt". As a slang word, it is speculated to come from *самопальный* "homemade, homebrewed", which is thought to be a humorous paronomastic contamination of *самодельный* "self-made" with *самопал* "zip gun".

The word *самопал*, literally "self-firing", is a revived XVI century word. Originally it described a kind of firearm used by the Russian army, which had later fallen out of use. The adjective *самопальный* in its original meaning outlived the firearm, and came to mean "related to firearms", but also fell out of use by XVIII century.

Whatever the way *палёнка* came to mean "counterfeit spirit", it ultimately comes from the same root, meaning "to burn", as the Czech word.